# SQL query not running where column name is reserved word

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a column name which is a SQL reserved word, how do I in query explorer in SQL Server Management Studio run this query

```
SELECT Name, [myTable].Schema
FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `[` `]` around your reserved word.

```
SELECT [Name], myTable.[Schema]
FROM myTable
```

Actually it doesn't hurt to add brackets around every segment:

```
SELECT [Name], [myTable].[Schema]
FROM [myTable]
```

Comment: Arggh.  Don't add brackets around every name.  That just makes queries harder to write and to read.  Simply avoid reserved words and unacceptable characters.

Answer (score 1):

Use brace over that reserved world.

```
SELECT [Name], [myTable].[Schema]
FROM [myTable]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeap, just use the brackets around the reserved world.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, square brackets helps. You don't even have to mention table name while using reserve words in square brackets(if that's what you named your table column).

```
SELECT [Name], [Schema]
FROM   myTable
```

You can even give a white space using square brackets to a column name.
Eg:

`SELECT [Name]   as [Table Name]
        [Schema] as [Column Name]
 FROM   [myTable]`

And just a small tip (not advised) - You can also use a white space to the column name using square brackets.
Eg: `CREATE TABLE Sample_table ([Order Number] INT)`

Answer (score 1):

In place of the proprietary square brackets `[identifier]` you better use Standard SQL's double quoted `"identifier"` which is supported by (probably) every DBMS including [MS SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874(v=sql.110).aspx):

```
SELECT Name, "Schema"
FROM myTable
```